linguistics terminology "way of speaking"
There is an entertaining video "If Americans spoke like French" https://www.youtube.com/shorts/DFgJVk-9QG0 where French is overly literally translated into English, so a sentence might be "Sorry, what is this that you have said?"  (instead of "I'm sorry, what did you say?")
I wonder if there is a linguistics term meaning "the way people speak" that could be properly applied to the above situation.
For example,

Grammar is different between these two languages.
The spelling varies, between these two dialects.
___ is different, between these two languages.

where ___ means something like "the way people speak".
In fact, this "the way people speak" adds complexity to language learning, since you cannot simply translate word-for-word.   Entirely different expressions are required.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom_(language_structure)

@LjL thanks. Yes this is probably the answer: "Idiom, also called idiomaticness or idiomaticity."

That has a grammar mistake: If Americans spoke like the French do. The funniest one if you know French is cowly owl. It's because they are not translating meaning, they are translating the words literally. That's where the humor comes from.

You might be interested in this comic genious' interpretation of Thanksgiving: Le Grande Thanksgiving
by Art Buchwald, The Washington Post https://theboldsoul.lisataylorhuff.com/the_bold_soul/2013/11/explaining-thanksgiving-to-the-french-yeah-good-luck-with-that.html

@Sam I'm suspecting it is the answer, but all I have is that Wikipedia article which isn't even very good, so I decided to just leave it as a comment...

@Lambie it's not a mistake if that is also a word-for-word translation from French. Not sure. By the way, will you learn Russian? It is impossible.  Spanish - ten times easier. ( verb of being omitted in present tense).

@Sam The French would be (Si les américains parlaient comme les français)  it's les français, the French.

Syntax describes how words are related and ordered to form larger units like phrases and sentences. One common element of syntax is word ordering, like how some languages typically use subject-verb-object but some use verb-subject-object, or how different languages may put adjectives before or after the noun they modify. Directly translating word-for-word between languages often does not work well because of different syntax rules between languages.

Thanks!  That makes sense. There may be multiple answers that apply to this same question.  On some level I am also imagining, even after you apply rules for let's say "verb inflection", and "word ordering", there still remains more differences.   A selection of entirely different words could be used to communicate a concept, for example.

@Sam there are many ways that languages can differ. E.g. it's common for languages to lack words for "to have" or "to be", and a number of languages lack conjunctions like "and" and "but".
